# Input Method without a view

Tags: android

I have a service that gets Unicode characters over WiFi, which should be entered to a EditText in which the cursor is currently positioned (sort of a remote desktop)

I'm trying to figure out what will be the best way to input text to EditText views (and similar view) without showing a keyboard layout on the screen.

Is the IME the right direction? or is there a way to inject a keypress (Unicode char) to the system?

Thanks!

Comment: unicode is not a representation. what encoding do you get the characters in ? also, a keypress is not a char. you can simply use setText on your EditText

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution:

I've imported an IME (actually used Google
s SoftKeyboard sample to test my solution) to my Server project.

Overridden the InputMethodService onEvaluateInputViewShown() and returned false to hide the keyboard view.

Now I'm calling the onKey() function with the requested char. This way I'm passing Unicode chars to the view in focus.

Anyone has a better way?